# Java IBM-860 Encoding Problems

Tags: java, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I have a printer that is configured to work with PC860 Codepage.

According with this site (http://www.madore.org/~david/computers/unicode/cstab.html#CP860), we have the following:

```
HEX    CHAR
0xB3   │
0x86   Á
```

So, I'm trying to send the following String to the Printer

```
Sring test = "\u00B3Á\u00B3"
```

But I get undesired results beside encoding I use when calling String.getBytes():

Using `ISO-8859-1`, `0xB3`prints correctly but `Á`don't. `Á` was mapped to `0xC1` instead.

Using `IBM-860`, `Á` prints correctly but `\u00B3`don't. `\u00B3` was mapped to `0x3F`.

Using `ISO-8859-1`, if I change the String to `\u00B3\u0086\u00B3`(replacing `À` to it's HEX value) the correct result is achieved.

I could't realize what I'm doing wrong. Could anybody shows what I'm missing?

```
void printString(String str) throws IOException {

    //os is a OutputStream

    //Using IBM-860 Charset...
    os.write(str.getBytes(Charset.forName("IBM-860")));

    //Using ISO-8859-1 Charset...
    os.write(str.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java strings are *always* UTF-16 encoded - so you need to use the UTF-16 encoding for the characters that you want to use:

```
String test = "│Á";
os.write(test.getBytes(Charset.forName("IBM-860")));
```

If you already know what the byte-sequence looks like and/or your encoding is not supported by the JVM, then don't use a String; write the bytes directly to the `OutputStream`:

```
byte[] b = { (byte) 0xB3, (byte) 0x86 };
os.write(b);
```

Comment: Hello @ErwinBolwidt, thanks a lot, it worked! But just to clarify: When I use the unicode representation, like `\u00B3`, why it doesn't work? Should't `\u00B3` be mapped to `|`and then stored as UTF-16 on the same way as you did above?

Comment: @regisxp The unicode character `\u00b3` is the superscript 3 character (`³`), not the pipe character. https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b3/index.htm